# Update text in <h4> with the same ID/Class on button/link click

Tags: javascript

I have two `<h4>` with the same class of "modal-title", and two buttons with ID & Class - "Reserve" and "Enquire". By pressing on button "Reserve", I want the `H4` to change to "Reserve", and when clicking on "Enquire" button, the text in `H4` should change accordingly.

The problem is, I have two containers which use the same buttons to interact with 'fixed' `H4` element, if I use "Reserve" button in Container 1, the `H4` will change successfully, if I then proceed clicking on "Enquire" button in Container 2, the `H4` element will not update to "Enquire" text, but it will however change if I use "Enquire" button in Container 1 instead. Why is that? And how can I make them function simultaneously? (in parallel) In fact, is there a simple way of achieving this?

```
<h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
```

Container 1:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
   <a id="reserve" class="reserve">Change to Reserve</a>
   <a id="enquire" class="enquire">Change to Enquire</a>
</div>
```

Container 2:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
   <a id="enquire" class="enquire">Change to Enquire</a>
   <a id="reserve" class="reserve">Change to Reserve</a>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var btnEnquire =  document.getElementById("enquire");
var btnReserve =  document.getElementById("reserve");
btnEnquire.onclick = function(){
    var enquireTxt = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-title");
    for (var i = 0; i < enquireTxt.length; i++) {
      enquireTxt[i].innerText = "Enquire";
    }
}
btnReserve.onclick = function(){
    var reserveTxt = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-title");
    for (var i = 0; i < reserveTxt.length; i++) {
      reserveTxt[i].innerText = "Reserve";
    }
}
```

(According to a few StackOverflow comments, this is the only way to return a value when using getElementsByClassName)

Comment: Are you saying you have two buttons with the same `id`? That should never happen. Each `id` should be unique.

Comment: I am aware, thus, I need to somehow use two buttons with the same class.

Comment: First of all. I don't see any buttons, I only see link tags. Second, I don't understand what you are trying to do...

Comment: This is where I am struggling. Perhaps, there is another way to achieve what I desire. I just don't want to have different IDs for the buttons that have identical function.

Comment: @zafira.404 https://jsfiddle.net/twoa3xox/- what's wrong here?? cant understand what you want.

Comment: My bad, links that serve as buttons.

Comment: `id`'s should **NEVER** be duplicated - that's invalid HTML. `document.querySelectorAll(".yourClassNameHere")` will collect all the elements that match the class name you supply.

Comment: Pwnz22, add two more links so it makes 4 of them, and you will notice that they don't function as intended.  e.g.  <a id="reserve" class="reserve">Change to Reserve</a> <a id="reserve" class="reserve">Change to Reserve</a>

Comment: And then how would I use querySelectorAll? Just add a 'reserve' or 'enquiry' function to it? I apologise for not been clear, I am very new to JavaScript.

Comment: Once you have the returned `node list` from `querySelectorAll()`, you can loop through the list and add event handlers to all the elements. That event handler can be the same for all the elements.

Comment: I tried the code like others, and confirm there is no problem with it. The text switches as one clicks on the anchors in both ways.

Comment: Could you please show me an example? Thank you.

Comment: @zafira.404 https://jsfiddle.net/twoa3xox/2/ - is that what you wanted?

Comment: @zafira.404 https://jsfiddle.net/twoa3xox/4/

Comment: Exactly that! Thank you so much to both of you, pwnz22 and Scott Marcus!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how you can avoid duplicate `id`s, but handle groups of elements. It isolates the repetition of the function by extracting that and then just calling the function with the necessary data via the button clicks.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  var btnEnquire =  document.getElementById("btnEnquire");
  var btnReserve =  document.getElementById("btnReserve");

  var modals = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-title");

  // 1. You can keep the button event handlers separate *****
  btnEnquire.addEventListener("click", function(){
    changeVal("Enquire");
  });

  btnReserve.addEventListener("click", function(){
    changeVal("Reserve");
  });
  // *********************************************************
  
  // 2. Or, you could combine into more compact code: ********
  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".myButton");
  buttons.forEach(function(button){
     button.addEventListener("click", function(){
       changeVal(this.textContent);
     });
  });
  // *********************************************************

  // The main functionality has been extracted and exists only once
  // However, it will produce different results based on what you
  // pass into it.
  function changeVal(val){
    for (var i = 0; i < modals.length; i++) {
      modals[i].textContent = val;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="btnEnquire" class="myButton">Enquire</button>
<button id="btnReserve" class="myButton">Reserve</button>

<h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
Container 1:

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
   <a id="reserve" class="reserve">Change to Reserve</a>
   <a id="enquire" class="reserve">Change to Enquire</a>
</div>

<h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
Container 2:

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
   <a id="enquire" class="reserve">Change to Enquire</a>
   <a id="reserve" class="reserve">Change to Reserve</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, Scott. Will be using this code snippet as it's clean and doesn't duplicate any code.

Answer (score 2):

You should never assign the same Id to multiple elements. Instead, use the class reference only and loop over the results (like you did with 'modal-title') to add your click handlers.

```js
var btnEnquire =  document.getElementsByClassName("enquire");
var btnReserve =  document.getElementsByClassName("reserve");

for (var i = 0; i < btnEnquire.length; i++) {
    btnEnquire[i].onclick = function(){
    var enquireTxt = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-title");
        for (var i = 0; i < enquireTxt.length; i++) {
          enquireTxt[i].innerText = "Enquire";
        }
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < btnReserve.length; i++) {
    btnReserve[i].onclick = function(){
    var reserveTxt = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-title");
        for (var i = 0; i < reserveTxt.length; i++) {
          reserveTxt[i].innerText = "Reserve";
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
   <a class="reserve" href="#">Change to Reserve</a>
   <a class="enquire" href="#">Change to Enquire</a>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
   <a class="enquire" href="#">Change to Enquire</a>
   <a class="reserve" href="#">Change to Reserve</a>
</div>
```

Would be cleaner even to use an id only for `modal-title` so you wouldn't need the nested loop.

Comment: But, this doesn't really address the main issue which is that the function (with only minor differences) is duplicated .